# Need formula for basic IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am writing a basic scoring program for racing event. I need the excel function basically to make it as following pseudocode.

```
=If cell B1 =1, then cell C1=5
```

Comment: Is there something more to this? You are asking for a basic `If` statement `=IF(B1=1,5)` place in cell C1?

Comment: Seems pretty basic like Matt said

Comment: What should C1 be if B1 is something else?  If you put a formula in C1 to create a value, Excel needs to know what to do in all cases it can encounter.  The IF statement needs another argument for that: =IF(B1=1,5,"X"), where "X" is what it should use when B1 is not 1.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You may want to take a minute to read **[ask]** so you can understand how this site works and improve your question. What you are asking is a very basic function of Excel, so maybe a search of built-in help would be beneficial to you.

Comment: -1 Maybe usually you have a teacher you often ask but (and particularly when they're not there) you need to have other methods to find answers. You need to google things. The common abbreviation is STFW  which can go along with RTFM

Comment: @barlop Our comments are supposed to be constructive. New people make a lot of mistakes and don't understand how to use the site (I certainly did). We need to encourage them to help themselves, not make them wish they had never asked.

Comment: @CharlieRB STFW and RTFM are absolutely classical things said to indicate how they can help themselves. Particularly relevant when something is very very easily googlable. If you don't want to discourage him then perhaps you can protest the -4 downvotes 0 upvotes his question has justifiably currently earned him.

Comment: @barlop I didn't say it wasn't a poorly constructed question. Using those acronyms might be offensive to someone if they understand the profanity included. All I'm saying is we, as a community, agree to [be nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice) when conducting ourselves here.

Comment: @CharlieRB there's nothing nasty about telling somebody there's that common acronym.. I first heard that acronym in a class in a  teacher in a university running a summer school program about 10 years ago. The acronym has a swear word in it but we are adults and you should be too. If an acronym unfortunately has a letter that stands for a swear word then don't get upset. I didn't make the acronym up. And I wasn't using  a swear word at him. Spine up.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an IF statement which follows the following format:

```
IF(logical test,[result if true],[result if false])
*note that there does not necessarily have to be an outcome for false
(it will just list FALSE as the result if the result of the logical
test is not true or equal to the statement that you test for.)
```

Therefore, in your case, what you are looking for is:

```
=IF(B1=1,5)
```